# How do you get a value onClick from outside the anchor that is clicked?

Tags: jquery

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<tr id="record_1" >
<td id="name_1"><a href="#" id="logNameAndValue">Charles Dickens</a></td><td id="value_1">A Christmas Carol</td>
</tr>
```

How can I print out `name=Charles Dickens value=A Christmas Carol` by partially using the following jQuery:

```
$('#logNameAndValue').click( function(event){
    name=?
    value=?
    console.log("name=" + name + " value=" + value);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#logNameAndValue').click(function(event){
    name = $(this).text();
    value = $(this).parent().next().text();
    console.log("name=" + name + " value=" + value);
});
```

Comment: That will work for this case, but if he happens to change the structure of the table, then that won't work.

Comment: @shoebox639 - That's true. But the OP specifically says, "Assuming the following HTML" which tells me that this is the HTML he's worried about. If that changes, he'll have to update the script too. The same could be said about your solution as well...what if the IDs change?

Answer (score 1):

```
name = $(this).text()
value = $('#value_' + $(this).attr('id').substring($(this).attr('id').length-1)).text()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#logNameAndValue').click( function(event){ 
    name=$(this).text();
    value=$(this).parent().next("td").text();
    console.log("name=" + name + " value=" + value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the click event function, the value would be $(this).siblings('td').text() I believe, and the name would be $(this).text().